# Calculating Edit distance between pandas dataframe column values and a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, edit-distance

I have one column in a pandas dataframe (it's actually fairly large, about 1.5 million rows of text data) that I want to compare against one string. For a simple sanity check/test, I wanted to try this only on the first 100 rows to get an idea that it won't take super long to execute. So a minimum sample of the dataframe looks like this:

```
Text
Hello, this is Peter, what would you need me to help you with today? I need you
Good Morning, John here, are you calling regarding your cell phone bill? I am not
......
```

and I have a fixed string

```
"Can I help you today?"
```

What my goal is to get a similarity score (I am still deciding which metric I am using, Levenstein vs Jaccard or Cosine) but that's not my main question, to get a similarity score between each pandas dataframe value and the fixed string value, and then probably just sort them by order.

Here is the code I have written:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')

Levenstein = []
Counter = 0

for x in All_sentences.rows:
    while Counter < 100:
        distance = nltk.edit_distance(All_sentences['Text'], "what I wanted 
        to calling because I lost my  ATM card debit card")
        Levenstein.append(distance)
        Counter +=1
```

when I run this code, firstly, it pops up a dialog box with the NLTK downloader

```
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did 
not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Secondly, I am seeing a message that says (below my code that is running but not finishing the execution):

```
​showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
```

And I am waiting for a long time and nothing shows up in the output (it is still running, I only see the  * that it is still processing).

What are those messages and most importantly, why would it take so long to process if I am only doing a sample comparison of 100 values instead of the whole dataset?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Hello fellow Philadelphian:) I am not quiet sure what does that mean? I do work at a corporation if that's what you mean? I can imoprt nltk but when I run nltk.download() it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Hello! Most corporations are behind firewalls/proxies. If you're working right now (i.e. on your corporation's network), you need to add logic to get past the proxy. You can do that by setting your `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables, or using `nltk.set_proxy()`

Comment: Yea, I have tried that per the suggestion of the answer below but that does not seem to change anything in my output

Comment: I mean you can't use `http://proxy.example.com:3128`. You have to find *your* proxy URL.

Comment: I think `ipconfig` is your friend. Open up cmd and type that in. I think it *should* list the proxy. It'll be something like `http://proxy.your_corps_name.com:some_port`. If you have chrome you can go to `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`, and it should be listed there. HTH.

Comment: When I go to Local Area NetWork LAN Settings where it says Proxy Server, it says Use a proxy server for your LAN(...) that is all greyed out unchecked, the address is blank, there is only a number in the port. When I type ipconfig that you listed, it just likes connection-specific DNS suffix, IPv4 address, Subnet Mask and Default Gateway, is it one of these 4?

Comment: @Matt Messersmith, can you help out by any chance? Is it either of these 4? I don't see anything like what you wrote when i type ipconfig in the command line

Comment: The `http://proxy.your_corps_name.com:some_port` is a colloquialism, it is not necessarily what your proxy url will look like (kind of like how we capitalize class names: but the language doesn't force you to do that). I really can't help you here: it's almost certainly a proxy issue. When in doubt, just *try* using the different urls you see listed from `ipconfig`. One of them *might* work. Seriously, though, this really isn't my area of expertise. I do not know exactly how to get proxy info on windows...sorry

Comment: You could ask another question: it might be best to put it on super user or something like that, though (not stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Look, I think the problem is within downloading NLTK packages. First, make sure your internet connection is working and stable. Then, open the terminal and write the following commands:

```
$ python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
```

This will open the python shell and download the popular packages in NTLK. This would look like this:
[image]
Now, run the code after deleting:

```
nltk.download()
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

Comment: is there another way I can download nltk? I think my terminal is not properly setup here because when I go to the cmd and type the above, it gives me the 'nltk.download' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' message

Comment: Did you install `nltk`??

Comment: I think so because if I type import nltk in my jupyter notebook, it executes that command

Comment: what happens when I type in nltk.download() in jupyter notebook is it gives me the NLTK downloader with the message, [WinError 10060] A Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond

Comment: try using proxy with the following command `nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128)'`

Comment: this would be where exactly? in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: before `nltk.download('popular')`. And use a real proxy, I have used a dummy one (`http://proxy.example.com:3128`) just as an example.

Comment: ok I am using the exact one you just stated, nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128'), it's still the same thing, it's just executing (as in showing the *) and not doing anything else differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185565/discussion-between-anwarvic-and-mkheifetz).